# Which book is the Murderer's Gloves magic item from?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, product-identification

Which book is the Murderer's Gloves magic item from?

I tried googling it, but no luck. It is supposed to be good for rogues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Complete Mage*, page 133. They let you turn invisible after a Sneak Attack.